# function calling within a class C++

Tags: c++, calling-convention

Within the same class I have

```
Executive::Executive(std::istream& fin){

std::ifstream dFin(argv[2]);

if(!dFin.is_open()){
    std::cout <<"Could not open directives file.";
    std::cout <<endl;
}
else{
    std::string directive;
    dFin >>directive;

    int x;
    dFin >>x;


    if(directive=="print"){

    }
```

and the function

```
void Executive::print(int i) const{

if(i>MAX_NUM_POLYNOMIALS){
    std::cout <<"Sorry, " <<i <<" is not within the known polynomials.";
    std::cout <<endl;
}
else{       

    pNom[i].print(std::cout);
    std::cout << i <<'\n';
}
```

}

In the last bit of the first code, how do I call the print function from the second code? They're in the same class, and I don't want to confuse calling it with the print function being called from another class in the second part.

Comment: I do not understand your concern. You can simply call print, and when you need to call that with a separate class, you will use the myAnotherClass.print(..) pattern, no?

Comment: Did you try "print(x);"? What error did you get?

Answer (score 3):

In short, there is no problem in calling the print method directly in here. There are some scenarios below though for consideration.

If you have a print method in a different class, you would simply use `myAnotherClass.print(...)`.

If you need to call a print method explicitly from the base class, you can use the base class scope explicitly as presented in the example at the bottom, such as `MyBaseClass::print(...)`

It is a simple case when you cannot have any clash except if you have a print method in the global scope or a namespace being used.

If it is in the global area, you would call it with ::print(...), and if it is in a namespace, you could use myNamespace::print(...)

Try to avoid "this->" at all costs, and leave that as the last resort. If you had a 'print' argumnt in the method where you are calling print, that could be one case if you could not change the argument name otherwise for some reason.

Finally, after the theoretical lesson, here goes the practical example:

```
Executive::Executive(std::istream& fin){

std::ifstream dFin(argv[2]);

if(!dFin.is_open()){
    std::cout <<"Could not open directives file.";
    std::cout <<endl;
}
else{
    std::string directive;
    dFin >>directive;

    int x;
    dFin >>x;


    if(directive=="print") {
        print(x);                // calling the method of the current class
        MyBaseClass::print(x);     // calling the method of the base class
        myAnotherClass.print(x); // classing the method of a different class
        ::print(x);              // calling print in the global scope
        myNamespace::print(x);   // calling the method in a dedicated namespace
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be ABSOLUTELY sure you're calling your own function you can use the `this` keyword if it's not a static function or the class name if it is static.

`this->print(...);` or `Executive::print(...);`

Answer (score 0):

You can just fully qualify the member function to call:

```
Executive::Executive(std::istream& fin)
{
  // ...
  if(directive == "print")
  {
    Executive::print(x);
  }
  // ...
}
```

I should note that if you're adding a non-static `print` method to another *different* class there is no chance of a name collision here. That's because to actually call that method from outside of its containing class you have to refer to some instance to call it with.